# How to show an item overflow count based on the viewable height?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Given the following:

[image: Right column, showing the item count hidden]

http://jsfiddle.net/3ZP4v/2/

```
<ul>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    <li>Item</li>
    ....
</ul>
```

How can you handle the 2nd column, where on window resize, any items that are not visible show a "X more" where X is the # of items overflowed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/3ZP4v/5/

```
var ulHeight=$('ul').height();
var liHeight=$('li').height();
var elementsVisible=ulHeight/liHeight;
var elementsHidden=Math.ceil($('li').length-elementsVisible);
$('#showMore').html(elementsHidden+' MORE');

$('#showMore').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $('ul').animate({height:'+='+(elementsHidden*liHeight)+'px'},500);
});
```

what this code actually does is that it calculates the height of a single li, then divides the ul height by the li height to see how many lis are being shown right now, then it minuses the number of the shown elements from the whole number of lis. so we get the total number of hidden elements.

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onload = function(){

    var ul = document.getElementById('list');
    var li = ul.getElementsByTagName('LI') ;
    var more = document.getElementById('more');
    var unit = li[0].offsetHeight;
    var offset = 50; // Increase this value if you want a narrower list
    adjust();

    function adjust(){
        var h = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
        ul.style.height = (h - offset) + "px";
        ul.style.overflow = "hidden";
        more.innerHTML = Math.ceil(li.length - (parseInt(ul.style.height) / unit)) + " more";
    }

    more.onclick = function(){
        if(ul.offsetHeight < unit * li.length){
            ul.style.height = "";
            ul.style.overflow = "";
            more.innerHTML = "less";
        }else{
            adjust();
        }
    };

    window.onresize = function(){ adjust(); };

};
```

Working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5DX9h/1/)